# Call React Function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have code is below, I want my result is "Hello Mr. John Doe".

```
function formatname(name) {
    return name.fullName;
};

const name = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    fullName: function() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
};

const getName = (
    <h1>Hello Mr. {formatname(name)}</h1>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    getName,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But when I save it return is "Hello Mr. ", what I wrong in variable fullName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
const name = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    fullName: function() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
};
```

this is not refered to your variable name anymore. To solve, you need to bind this back to the name you declared:

```
formatname(name).bind(name)()
```

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Comment: Thanks , It working. Could you tel me ".blind(name)() what does it mean ?

Comment: Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.